# Getting null pointer exception when setting spinner view text

Tags: android, view, nullpointerexception, spinner

Below is the code invoked onItemSelected in a spinner. At times I am getting a null pointer exception even when the app is closed. The image of the bug is attached in this post.

```
        /**
         * Store the selected product
         * @param parent
         * @param view
         * @param position
         * @param id
         */
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            QuickListItem selectedSpinnerProduct = productAdapter.getItem(position);

            if (selectedSpinnerProduct != null) {
                mgrApp.storeSharedPrefLong(ConstantsQuickList.SHARED_PREF_PRODUCT_ID,
                        selectedSpinnerProduct.getId());
            }

            SpannableStringBuilder builder = getPendingCallCount(products,
                    selectedSpinnerProduct);

            ((TextView) view).setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

            //Hide the performance tracker as product will change
            ViewProspects.crdvPerformanceTracker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            populateSalesTracker(typeOfOperation,ConstantsProspects.INVALID_STRING);

        }
```

[Application cashed bug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgdKA.jpg)

Comment: For the time being i have put the code  (TextView) view).setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE); in a try catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **selectedSpinnerProduct** is null, you will have issue. So check everywhere **selectedSpinnerProduct** is used that it is null or not.

```
 if (selectedSpinnerProduct != null) {
                mgrApp.storeSharedPrefLong(ConstantsQuickList.SHARED_PREF_PRODUCT_ID,
                        selectedSpinnerProduct.getId());
 SpannableStringBuilder builder = getPendingCallCount(products,
                    selectedSpinnerProduct);

            ((TextView) view).setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            }
```

Comment: Instead of spoonfeeding code to the OP, please consider explaining how your code is different from the original code.

Comment: Thanks i guess, I have tried this approach too.

Comment: If your problem is solved, check the correct answer please @YashSharma

Comment: It's not yet being solved. Implemented the changes will test and update the correct solution. Thnx

Comment: What is the problem now? @YashSharma

Comment: Hi, yes, I add description to my answer. Of course the question is closed. @Edric

Comment: There is no problem. Just releasing the code this week and will observe the error. if that comes back will let you guys know of it. else will close the question. Thanks for the suggestions. The crash does not happen all the time. Its a random event.